# Веб авторизация на С#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, авторизация

В общим мусолил интернет, первоначальная задача была:
создать виндоус форм в которой будет загружаться определённый сайт и автологиниться, не получилось.
Сделал логин с использованием нажатия `button`, говорит что не верный логин и пароль. Проверял в эксплорере, все данные подходят.

Выкладываю тело программы, если кто знает как, выложите 2 примера - один по копке логин второй - автоматом после загрузки страницы.

вот мой код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            web.Navigate("http://public.servicebox.peugeot.com");
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 foreach (HtmlElement html in web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (html.GetAttribute("name") == "userid")
                {
                    html.SetAttribute("value", "AP34593969");
                }

                if (html.GetAttribute("name") == "password")
                {
                    html.SetAttribute("value", "mazdacx77");
                }

                web.Document.GetElementById("btsubmit").InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вынести `web.Document.GetElementById("btsubmit").InvokeMember("click");` за тело цикла.

Comment: Используйте наклоненные кавычки для оформления строки кода: **`**, а не **'**.